# Unable to add reference to third party WCF Service using Visual Studio

Tags: asp.net, .net, web-services, wcf, visual-studio-2012

I recently received an updated integration document from a third party web services provider. One of the changes indicated that there are updated services that are located at a new URL.

I proceeded to delete my existing reference in my .NET 3.5 console application (VS2012) and attempted to add a new one pointing to the updated URL but was unable to do so due to the following error and die disabled "Add" button:

[image: Error message]

I subsequently tried to restore the reference to the old URL (which worked a mere month ago when I initially added it) but that to gave the same error.

I did a bit of googling and found the following posts that were not very encouraging:

[Can't add Service Reference](http://forums.asp.net/t/1858236.aspx?Can%20t%20add%20Service%20Reference)

[Mixing Add Service Reference and WCF Web HTTP (a.k.a. REST) endpoint does not work](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/carlosfigueira/archive/2012/03/26/mixing-add-service-reference-and-wcf-web-http-a-k-a-rest-endpoint-does-not-work.aspx)

[Don’t use “Add Service Reference”!](http://devdump.wordpress.com/2009/01/05/dont-use-add-service-reference/)

The first link simply repeated my problem statement. The second suggested there is no hope for me and the third is of no relevance since I do not control the server side component.

I was hoping someone with some more WCF experience possibly point me in the right direction. I suppose my question is twofold:

1: Is this something I am doing wrong on my side or can it be a problem with configuration on the third party server?

2: Is there any way I can reasonably add a reference to those services in my project without using "Add Reference" in VS, using the WSDL which I am able to download?

Edit: Just to calrify, the URL resolves and I can see the service controls and descriptions in both my browser and the VS window where you attempt to resolve the WS but the ".../$metadata" part in the error message above is not part of the original URL I entered. original URL which resolves fine is http://service.somewhere/service234/thing and the error refers to http://service.somewhere/service234/thing/*_vti_bin/ListData.svc/$metadata*

Comment: contact the 3rd party. we can't answer for a 404.

Comment: Already did that. Just thought since they may take a while to respond, I'd ask some of the experienced minds here. Also, I suspect the 404 is slightly misleading since the URL resolves fine in my browser - it simply does not work when adding the reference in VS.

Comment: do they actually expose the metadata?

Comment: Well I suppose only they can answer that, which is why I also contacted them. It would seem not though. If they did before, they don't anymore. Is the error is question representative of a service that does not expose metadata?